# Youtube Iframe jQuery code fails on ajax website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

My webpage is full ajax navigation, when clicking through various links in the page and I have jQuery code being used on the page but it fails to load when clicking ajax links. I have tried using on. live. delegated. but they all did not work.

I used the below code I found on here to reload my jquery code

```
//function initialise(){
     $('.youtube iframe').each( function(){
        // return if we're dealing with google ads iframe
        if ( typeof $(this).attr('src') == 'undefined' ) return;
        var $this_video = $(this),
            src_attr = $this_video.attr('src'),
            wmode_character = src_attr.indexOf( '?' ) == -1 ? '?' : '&amp;',
            this_src = src_attr + wmode_character + 'wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;theme=light';
        $this_video.attr('src',this_src);
    } );

        };

//  $(document).ready(function(){
        initialise();
    });

//  $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        initialise();
    });
```

But when I use this code the iframe on the page seems stucked in a loop.I assume it's stuck in the loop because the ajax call checks for an update every few seconds but I want to know how I can apply my jQuery iframe code and not have it reloaded every few seconds

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated. Show how you're using `.delegate()`

Comment: Disregard my last comment - noticed you were using `.each()`, not an event handler. `$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function(event, request) { console.log('AJAX COMPLETE: ', event, request) });` should work. What happens if you add some console logs to the initialize function and look for them on ajax complete?

Comment: I'm no longer using it, as it didn't seem to work. Only the above code worked for me but the iframe keeps reloading every few seconds.

Comment: Perhaps that's because `ajaxComplete` is firing on other AJAX events? Look whats inside the `event` itself and try filtering it. Turn on `XMLHTTPRequest` logging in your dev tools and see how many requests are being made

Comment: It shows a request just about every 250ms in chrome network tool.

Comment: That would explain why it's refreshing then. Look more into what that request is. Then as I was saying earlier, on your `ajaxComplete`, look into the `event`, make sure its NOT the request thats repeating every 250ms, wrap it in an if block, and you're good to go.

Comment: If that's too much work, just invoke `initialise()` in the AJAX callback of wherever you need, I assume navigation or something. But I'd check out what that AJAX request firing so often is regardless.